# how to fetch value of JsonResponse in android?

Tags: android, json

I want to fetch countdata using JsonParsing. How is it possible?
      My json Response is is,

```
 {"data":[{"l_id":"1","p_id":"5","user_id":"15"},{"l_id":"2","p_id":7","user_id":"16"}]}{"countdata":2}
```

countdata is Total number of data. I am able to fetch data but not able to countdata. please guide me.

I am able to fetch data for i_id,p_id and user_id Successfully and My code is,

```
private class GetDetail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlData);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects

                    String lId=jsonobject.getString(TAG_L_ID);
                    String pId=jsonobject.getString(TAG_P_ID);
                    String userId=jsonobject.getString(TAG_User_ID);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    }
```

But I am not able to fetch data for countdata. and give the error, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0

And my Code is,

```
private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        JSONObject jsonobject;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            arr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlCount);

            String strCount = jsonobject.getString("qdata");

            } catch (JSONException e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Please Guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Json is invalid.

Comment: @DanialHussain please suggest me that What is a mistake of my json? please guide me.

Comment: Your URL says `Webpage not available.`

Comment: @Pratik Ok then after how to fetch data for countdata? I am able to successfully get data for l_id,p_id,user_id and I send the code in stackoverflow. please guide.

Comment: Try it `jsonobject.getString("countdata");`

Comment: @Reena Haresh tells how to compose your valid json response.

Comment: @pratt Ya I get the my count data for using jsonobject.getString("countdata") but whenever I click on second item of listview for Like then get force close and get the error like,java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 011-25 and java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

Comment: @Reena that means you doing parsing wrong, after passing your array is not creating proper, and your json is also invalid.

Comment: @pratt How to setText on Textview while fetch strCount. I am using Listview with ViewHolder and I setText strCount for every item and increment by 1 when click on Selected item of Listview. I get strCount Successfully and Click on selected item Of listview then increment by 1 also. but how to set the text on Textview?

Comment: @Reena viewHolder.txtStrCount.setText(String.valueOf(strCount));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your json response in Invalid

Valid json :

```
{"data":[{"l_id":"1","p_id":"5","user_id":"15"},{"l_id":"2","p_id":"7","user_id":"16"}],"countdata":"2"}
```

How get countdata :

```
String strCount = jsonobject.getString("countdata");
```

Comment: How to setText on Textview while fetch strCount. I am using Listview with ViewHolder and I setText strCount for every item and increment by 1 when click on Selected item of Listview. I get strCount Successfully and Click on selected item Of listview then increment by 1 also. but how to set the text on Textview?

Comment: Ask new question with ur requirement.

Comment: Ok sure I post new Question in stackoverflow